# Header style changes depending on tsx or jsx extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jsx, chakra-ui

I have this simple function inside `app.tsx` that renders a table. The header is nicely visible (white on black).

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Thead, Tbody, Tr, Th, Td } from "@chakra-ui/react"

export default function App() {
  return(
    <Table variant="simple" size="sm">
      <Thead>
        <Tr>
          <Th>A</Th>
          <Th>B</Th>
        </Tr>
      </Thead>
      <Tbody>
        <Tr>
          <Td>a</Td>
          <Td>b</Td>
        </Tr>
      </Tbody>
    </Table>
  )
}
```

However, if I change the filename instead to `app.jsx`, the same table will render but with a header that is hard to see:

[image]

To replicate this:

```
git clone https://github.com/somguyth/chakra-ui-header-bug.git
cd chakra-ui-header-bug
npm install
npm run dev
```

Then open `localhost:9000` and change `app.jsx` to `app.tsx` and observe how the header color changes once the code recompiles.

The header element when it's nicely visible (`app.tsx`):
[image]

The header element when it is not (`app.jsx`):
[image]

**EDIT**: I was able to sort-of "fix" it by putting `<ChakraProvider theme={darkTheme}>` into `app.jsx` (in addition to `index.tsx`). Inspecting the element of the header to see why it was fixed, the class inside the `th` tag went back to the correct `css-4v3u8n`, instead of the incorrect `css-r10se1`. I don't know what this means or how to fix it properly (i.e., how to fix it without having to use `ChakraProvider` twice).

---

My `index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react"


import App from "./app"

const darkTheme = extendTheme({
  config: {
    useSystemColorMode: false,
    initialColorMode: "dark"
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <ChakraProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <App />
    </ChakraProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and my module rules in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: "ts-loader",
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/preset-react"]
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        fullySpecified: false,
      },
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
  ],
},
```

and my `.babel.rc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

and my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack serve"  
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.0.14",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.45.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Inspect that element in both cases with your web browsers inspector. For example in Chrome, right click the table header, choose inspect. Looks through the class names on the element, and the CSS styles that are present. Now change the file extension and do the same thing. What differences do you see?

Comment: My guess would be that `babel-loader` and `ts-loader` somehow caused the "@chakra-ui/react" module to be resolved to different files (it ships with both cjs and esm format). So your dark theme in `index.tsx` can't be passed to `app.jsx` because they use different React contexts. The problem is I don't know **how** it can happen, because all module resolution should be handled by webpack, unless babel and typescript inserted some helper function to the `import` in their outputs.

Comment: I also tried renaming `index.tsx` to `index.jsx` (and edit webpack config), this time it also use correct theme, supporting my theory above.

Comment: @SimonChan What would be a good way we can fix this, without having to refactor the entire project into either `tsx` or `jsx`?

Comment: @AlexWayne I've added that into the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because there are two versions of `@chakra-ui/react` package in your bundle, one in `cjs` format and one in `esm`. When using React Context, two copies of the same file will create two different React Contexts (it's same as calling `React.createContext` in two different files), so the Consumer in one copy can't get value from Provider in another version.

This can be verified by running `npx webpack build --mode production --profile --json=stats.json` and loading the `stats.json` file into [Webpack stats analyse tool](https://webpack.github.io/analyse/) which can give many internal info about your bundle:

[image]
[image]

(Webpack stats analyse tool showing there are two versions of `@chakra-ui/react` package)

---

The reason of duplicated `@chakra-ui/react` package is that your configurations make TypeScript transpiling files to CommonJS format, and Babel transpiling files to ESModule format, while `@chakra-ui/react`'s `package.json` has an `exports` field which specified different files for different import requests:

```
// @chakra-ui/react/package.json

"exports": {
  ".": {
    "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
    "default": "./dist/esm/index.js"
  }
}
```

([Webpack's documentation on package exports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/), basically, using `require` will import one file, and using `import` will import another file)

```
// Output of src/index.tsx just after ts-loader

"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var react_1 = __importDefault(require("react"));
var react_dom_1 = __importDefault(require("react-dom"));
var react_2 = require("@chakra-ui/react");
var app_1 = __importDefault(require("./app"));
var darkTheme = react_2.extendTheme({
    config: {
        useSystemColorMode: false,
        initialColorMode: "dark"
    }
});
react_dom_1.default.render(react_1.default.createElement(react_2.ChakraProvider, { theme: darkTheme },
    react_1.default.createElement(app_1.default, null)), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```
// Output of src/app.jsx just after babel-loader

import React from 'react';
import { Table, Thead, Tbody, Tr, Th, Td } from "@chakra-ui/react";
export default function App() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Table, {
    variant: "simple",
    size: "sm"
  }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Thead, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Tr, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Th, null, "A"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Th, null, "B"))), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Tbody, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Tr, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Td, null, "a"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Td, null, "b"))));
}
```

(You can use the [`inspect-loader`](https://github.com/peerigon/inspect-loader) to debug loader outputs)

---

To resolve this issue, you can change your `tsconfig.json` to output ESModule:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "module": "ESNext",
  "moduleResolution": "node"
}
```